# Having trouble with a purge command in Discord-Rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As you can see by the title I'm having trouble with Discord-Rewrite.
I have been looking on the api page for the past few days, in multiple discord API servers looking for help and even here on Stack Overflow and only seen code for the Async Branch.

I've tried looking around on youtube for tutorials as well but there weren't that many for python and was mainly dedicated on JavaScript so I tried JavaScript and I have a working purge command but I want to stick to using python as I'm more comfortable with that compared to JavaScript.

I'd really appreciate it if someone was willing to help out whether its posting working code, giving me a guideline, or even the right place to look. Any type of help will be appreciated as I've been stuck for a few days trying to get something working and the closest thing I got was having it delete the bots own message which just stated how many messages it deleted, in this case just 1 (Its own message).

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Are you just looking for [`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge)?  What exactly would you want this command to do?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh so basically, im wanting it if someone does !purge <int> it will clear the amount of messages a user stated after the !purge .. i have a version on my bot at the moment but it just clears all messages from the bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge) to delete messages from a certain channel. Your bot will need the `manage_messages` permission.

```
@bot.command()
async def purge(ctx, amount: int):
    deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send(f"Deleted {len(deleted)} messages")
```